Cors and React with no local server
I am trying to fetch data from https://dummyjson.com/auth/login
My request looks like this:
    const getArticles = async () => {
      const data = await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/auth/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json",'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true' },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: "emilys",
          password: "emilyspass",
          expiresInMins: 30, // optional, defaults to 60
        }),
        credentials: "include", // Include cookies (e.g., accessToken) in the request
      });
    };

I am getting the error below:


Remove credentials: "include". That triggers an OPTIONS call, which dummyjson doesn't include as an approved method in their access-control-allow-methods header (allowed methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE). Unless there is a reason you need to pass cookies along, there's no need to use credentials in your request.
This works for me:
const getArticles = async () => {
  const data = await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/auth/login", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json",'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: "emilys",
      password: "emilyspass",
      expiresInMins: 30, // optional, defaults to 60
    })
  });
};

...and I received the following response:
{
  "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJlbWlseXMiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImVtaWx5LmpvaG5zb25AeC5kdW1teWpzb24uY29tIiwiZmlyc3ROYW1lIjoiRW1pbHkiLCJsYXN0TmFtZSI6IkpvaG5zb24iLCJnZW5kZXIiOiJmZW1hbGUiLCJpbWFnZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vZHVtbXlqc29uLmNvbS9pY29uL2VtaWx5cy8xMjgiLCJpYXQiOjE3MjcyOTc4MTAsImV4cCI6MTcyNzI5OTYxMH0.FdD1MZ1AppmkC05XiYhu1hT6AK_6WC4f0rc62q31-aA",
  "refreshToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJlbWlseXMiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImVtaWx5LmpvaG5zb25AeC5kdW1teWpzb24uY29tIiwiZmlyc3ROYW1lIjoiRW1pbHkiLCJsYXN0TmFtZSI6IkpvaG5zb24iLCJnZW5kZXIiOiJmZW1hbGUiLCJpbWFnZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vZHVtbXlqc29uLmNvbS9pY29uL2VtaWx5cy8xMjgiLCJpYXQiOjE3MjcyOTc4MTAsImV4cCI6MTcyOTg4OTgxMH0.lfjT0OIWFsL5M_xFlZlBQcISVfr90GxJXytXbfLo5s0",
  "id": 1,
  "username": "emilys",
  "email": "emily.johnson@x.dummyjson.com",
  "firstName": "Emily",
  "lastName": "Johnson",
  "gender": "female",
  "image": "https://dummyjson.com/icon/emilys/128"
}

I hope this helps.

That works! Thanks a lot!
